# Count instances of 'a' using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I have a homework assignment for beginning Java to count the instances of 'a' in a word or phrase.  I am receiving the following errors.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of >range: 4
>     at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
>     at aHomework.aHomework.countAInWord(aHomework.java:26)
>     at aHomework.aHomework.main(aHomework.java:13)
>   Java Result: 1

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class aHomework 
{
public static void main( String [] args )
{
    Scanner inputW = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input = inputW.nextLine();
    countAInWord(input, input.length());    
}

public static void countAInWord( String w , int n)
   {

 int aCount = 0;
 if ( n > 0 )
 {
     if (w.charAt(n) == 'a')
     {
         aCount++;
     }
     else
     {
         n = n-1;
         countAInWord(w, n);
     }
 }
 else
     System.out.println("The number of A's is " + aCount);
   }
}
```

I have been searching for recursion problems and have learned a lot.

However I would prefer to fix my code instead of just coping someone elses.

So if someone would be so kind as to tell me why I am receiving the above errors I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `String#charAt(n)` is what's giving the index out of bounds. It should be `n-1`. Also, shouldn't you return `int` in this recursion? Otherwise, I don't think you are using the recursion at all.

Comment: You are correct I was using recursion at all in the above example.  I updated my code below to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error is because you set n to be input.length().
Say the string is "halo", input.length() will return 4.

But when you're using string.charAt() method, the string indexing is 0-based that means, the maximum you can call is string.charAt(3) which should return 'o'. But since you are calling your recursive function with n=4, in your code it will call string.charAt(4) which is OutOfBound in that string. Thus you get that error. :)

try calling your recursive method with input.length()-1 
:D

```
public static void main( String [] args )
{
    Scanner inputW = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input = inputW.nextLine();
    countAInWord(input, input.length()-1);    
}
```

Some other bugs: (See my comment in the code)

```
public static void countAInWord( String w , int n)
{

int aCount = 0; // Everytime you enter this recursive function, it will reset to 0, which should not be the case.
if ( n > 0 )
{
     if (w.charAt(n) == 'a')
     {
         aCount++;
         // Yeah you found an 'a', then what? You should call the recursive function again to continue checking. (like how you do it in the else function below)
     }
     else
     {
         n = n-1;
         countAInWord(w, n);
     }
 }
 else
     System.out.println("The number of A's is " + aCount);
   }
}
```

Comment: Wow that worked.  But my program is now not outputting the number of times that the letter 'a' occurs.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I feel like I should hit my head for forgetting that.

Comment: @user2909519 no prob man! and actually, you should have aCount inside the recursive function, so that you can store the numberof 'a'. Currently, you declare it locally in the recursive function. Thus it will reset to 0 everytime you enter the function.

Comment: @user2909519 and yeah, you should call the recursive function too when you find the character 'a'. Currently your code will just stop when it finds 'a' hence it never print any output if you have 'a' in your string :)

Comment: So I updated the recursion method to look like this --> `if ( n >= 0 )
     {
         if (w.charAt(n) == 'a')
         {
             a++;
             n = n-1;
             countAInWord(w, n, a);
         }
         else
         {
             System.out.println("The number of A's is " + a);
         }
     }
     
   }`

Comment: No that wont work will it.  Sorry let me rethink the code real quick to add more base to the 'if' statements

Comment: thank you for the help.  I added an extra else statement to the recursion that fed into itself if no 'a' was found `else
         {
             n = n-1;
             countAInWord(w, n, a);
         }` .  Also I put the `System.out.println("The number of A's is " + a);` outside of the original if statement of the method.  Thank you for the time and help.

Comment: @user2909519 yup that should do the trick. :) glad I could help :D

Answer (score 0):

To answer the problem you have for your output

The variable `aCount` should be declared as one of the argument in your function like this  `countAInWord(String w , int n, int aCount)`  , so that the value of `aCount` can be passed into each iteration of the function

This because the variable declared in a function is only accessible within the function.

In your case every time the function countAInword is called, a new `aCount` is declared  and any increment made to that variable only affect that instance of aCount in that function call.

When you call the same function again, the value is not passed into that function call. Instead another of `aCount` is declared again.

Thus when you finally print the value of `aCount`, you are printing the instance of `aCount` of the very last function call.

Lastly, you should remove the else statement as the codes within should be executed regardless if an 'a' was found in that iteration

Hope this helps